# How can I call a JavaScript library at only server side with Spring Boot?

Tags: javascript, java, spring

I need to call JavaScript library on server side, which result will be returned to the user through Java.
This library uses many external JavaScript library, so it's not a single .js file.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of options, but without more context, we can only guess.

- Nashorn/GraalVM to execute Javascript from Java, but it depends on the library you're trying to invoke
- Install Node.js on the server, write a Node.js script which uses that lib and invoke the script from Java. Depending on the complexity of the use case and how often you're trying to do this, maybe write a microservice in Node.js and call it from Java via REST.